# I want to add a folder subdirectory to the URL in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

im trying to upload a laravel 5.7 project to a Cpanel shared hosting that already has other projects uploaded. My problem is, after following the laravel tutorials and moving the contents of the public folder to a subdirectory on public_html, only the front page is working, the project directory looks like this:

sharedhostingroot/

```
 /laravelproject

 /public_html/laravelproject
```

The problem im facing is that when i load the front page with the URL domain/laravelprojectfolder it works fine but when i go to another view the URL changes to domain/route, the laravelprojectfolder part of the URL gets deleted.

My understanding if i should change .htaccess file but im not really sure how this is my actual .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /citas_oncologico/$1 [R=302,NC,L]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Since i'm not really sure how to properly edit the file without breaking the app, i appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: It would be helpful to the OP and the others if you could explain what you answer does to resolve the OP's issue